# Node Env not set?

Tags: iisnode, kudu

This is a general question though I haven't found where I am going wrong. 
Using Windows Server with Azures kudu stand alone to host a local project.
Also using React, Webpack, Redux

Windows environment var is set to production
Package.json has set NODE_ENV=production && etc.. for 
  both start and build scripts
web.config has iisnode node_env=production

running node I get the node_env is indeed production
However when I build it's giving me the development build when I do something like

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./buildProduction.js')
}
else {
  module.exports = require('./buildDevelopment.js')
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Please clarify question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the same conclusion and searched why this is and thanks to neagtivetwelve for the comment @ https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1720

In short setting

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
}),
```

fixes the issue. Instead of

```
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV,
    }),
```

Even though I have in the build script to set the session NODE_ENV var and set within the system environment vars I would still get the wrong result until this change was made even though opening node from cmd and typing process.env.NODE_ENV yields the correct result.
Anyway I hope it helps someone else.